# How do I add a legend in ggplot2 using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been searching around the internet for an answer to my question, but so far all I've found is people who ask the same question, but have different circumstances then me.

Most people have two or more data sets on their ggplot and are adding a legend to show which one is which.  I, however, have a single line plotted, but there are multiple colors within the line.

Here's a picture of my output for further clarification:

[image]

I want to create a legend to specify what each color means.

Here is my code:

```
p04 <- read.csv("p04_datalog.csv",header=TRUE)

#The following line activates the ggplot2 add-on
library(ggplot2)

#This line will eliminate all -1 values for GS_ReelRaiseLowerAngle
p04_NoNegative <- subset(p04, p04$GS_ReelRaiseLowerAngle != -1)

#This creates an array of colors that are to be used with the plotting scripts

fieldcolors <- ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Out of Bounds","black",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field ==
 "Clumping","Orange",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Down","purple",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == 
 "High Moisture","darkblue",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "High Thin","pink",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == 
 "High Weeds","green",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Low Moisture","cyan",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == 
 "Low Thin","white",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Low Weeds","green4",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == 
 "Medium Thin","red",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Medium Weeds","yellowgreen",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == 
 "Short Hieght","tan2",ifelse(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field == "Tall Hieght","tan","brown")))))))))))))

x_axis <- seq(0,6000,10)
x_axis_ef <- seq(0,6000,500)

#The following lines generate a line plot of reel height for the entire field with colors
ggplot(p04_NoNegative, aes(x=Distance.Traveled, y=GS_ReelRaiseLowerAngle)) + 
  geom_line(color=fieldcolors,size=1.1) + ggtitle("p04 entire field") + ylim(0,0.6) +
  ylab("Reel Height (angle)")+ xlab("Distance (m)") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_axis_ef) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,5000))
```

I am fairly new to R and ggplot (I started just 3 days ago) so my code may not be the most efficient method, but it gets the job done.

I need to add a legend so people reading the graphic can know what each color represents. ex. bright green represents "High Weeds".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ditch your whole long `ifelse` monstrosity and just modify the `ggplot` call to be:

```
ggplot(p04_NoNegative, aes(x=Distance.Traveled, y=GS_ReelRaiseLowerAngle)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=GS_Field),size=1.1) + 
  ggtitle("p04 entire field") + ylim(0,0.6) +
  ylab("Reel Height (angle)")+ xlab("Distance (m)") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_axis_ef) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,5000))
```

You can set the colors via `scale_color_manual` (assuming `GS_Field` is a factor, I suppose).

The idea here is that ggplot automatically attempts to generate a legend when you *map* aesthetics inside of `aes()`. Otherwise you are *setting* the aesthetic.